# VSTO excel taskpane dockPositionRestrict propery logic?

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to control the docking position of a new taskpane i'm creating through C#/VSTO. I want to allow the pane to be docked only to right and left.

i don't follow the logic of the enumarator? which one should i use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpane.dockpositionrestrict.aspx

i assume you should use msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoHorizontal value.